# using gwt-dnd with new layout panels of gwt 2.0

Tags: gwt, layout, panel

I'd like to use gwt-dnd within an application that uses the new 2.0 layout panels.

however, gwt-dnd only accepts AbsolutePanel as its container for drag and drop.

is it possible to use AbsolutePanel within, say, a DockLayoutPanel?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use AbsolutePanel or DockPanel in gwt-dnd. But you can use FocusPanel. So you have to put FocusPanels whenever you want dnd available. 
Eg. you put: DockPanel -> north -> FocusPanel -> AbsolutePanel